# How to the get an object based on 2 criteria without doing extensive searching?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

It's hard to summarize this as a 1 line question. I have a class like this:

```
class Item
{
    int Count {get; set;}
    double Value {get; set;}
}
```

and a `List<Item>` that contains an arbitary number of `Item` values.

How can I get the `Item` with the lowest `Count` and the highest `Value`?

Performance is not important but elegance is, as I don't want to have huge nested loops to do this operation unless there is not elegant way, i.e. Linq, etc.

EDIT:

Here is a sample list that could have these `Items`:

```
{Count, Value}

{2, 10}, {6, 60}, {5, 21}, {4, 65}, {2, 35}, {4, 18}, {3, 55}, {7, 99}, {2, 25}
```

So here the value I want is `{2, 35}` because it has the lowest `Count` of all items, and for the items with the same `Count` values, it has the highest `Value`.

Comment: You want to get two items back one with the lowest Count and one with the highest Values, or you just want a single item returned where the Count is the lowest and the from this items has the highest Value?

Comment: Are these two separate queries? Also, does it have to be a `List<T>` or are you willing to maintain a purpose-built data-structure that allows for executing the desired queries efficiently on demand?

Comment: @BigL: Sorry I meant a single item that has the lowest `Count` but the highest `Value`.

Comment: @Joan: What if the item with the lowest count isn't the one with the highest value? Or is this a multi-objective optimization?

Comment: @Ani: I use a `List<T>` but I am not sure what you mean. You mean something like IEnumerable<T>? It might not matter too much I guess.

Comment: @Ani: Sorry yes there might be confusion, but as long as it has the lowest `Count`, the highest `Value` in that range is OK.

Comment: Incomplete/conflicting specs. Without 1 or more samples of a list and expected outcome this isn't a real question.

Comment: @Henk: Sorry you are right, just added some sample values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, now we've got a bit of clarity:

> as long as it has the lowest Count, the highest Value in that range is OK

It's easy...

```
var best = list.OrderBy(x => x.Count)
               .ThenByDescending(x => x.Value)
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

That will give `null` if the list is empty, but otherwise the item with the lowest count, and the one with the highest value if there are multiple with that count.

This is less efficient than it might be, as we could *really* do it in a single pass by creating a comparer to compare any two values - but this will certainly be the approach which gets the right element in the least code.

Comment: Thanks Jon, it's exactly how I wanted. By comparer you mean, inside the `Item` class?

Comment: @JoanVenge: Either making `Item` implement `IComparer` / `IComparer<T>`, or by providing a separate `IComparer<Item>` to pass to the `Max` or `Min` method.

Comment: Thanks Jon, btw just our of curiosity, if I had the `IComparer<T>`, would I just be able to use `Min`, and get the same result? Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully it works now, sadly not so elegant like Jon's

```
var res = (from i in items
           orderby i.Count ascending, i.Value descending
           select i).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Do you see why? Compare your answer to Jon's *carefully*.

Answer (score 1):

With [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) (which has `MinBy` and `MaxBy` operators), you can accomplish this easily in linear time (unfortunately needs an extra pass):

```
IEnumerable<item> items = ...

var minCount = items.Min(item => item.Count);
var minCountItemWithMaxValue = items.Where(item => item.Count == minCount)
                                    .MaxBy(item => item.Value);
```

With an appropriate `AllMinBy` extension that returned *all* the minimum items in a sequence (missing in morelinq sadly), you could make this even more efficient:

```
var minCountItemWithMaxValue = items.AllMinBy(item => item.Count)
                                    .MaxBy(item => item.Value);
```

**EDIT**:

Here's an (ugly) way to do it in O(1) space and O(n) time in a single pass with standard LINQ:

```
var minCountItemWithMaxValue = items.Aggregate(
                                (bestSoFar, next) =>
                                (next.Count < bestSoFar.Count) ? next :  
                                (next.Count > bestSoFar.Count) ? bestSoFar :
                                (next.Value > bestSoFar.Value) ? next : bestSoFar);
```

Comment: We really need a `MaxBy` with chained comparisons... but that would be tricky to express. Will have to think about it... (I did consider mentioning MoreLINQ, but felt it wasn't worth it in this case.)

Comment: @Jon: `AllMinBy` and `AllMaxBy` would be relatively easy, yes?

Comment: It wouldn't be ideal, as you'd have to keep a list of all the items which currently had the minimum value, etc. It would be nice to keep the O(1) memory aspect. I'm sure it's feasible with another interface, but whether it's worth the effort is a different matter.

Comment: @Jon: Btw, is "MoreLINQ" rather than "morelinq" your preferred capitalization? I use "morelinq" because that is how it is capitalized on the project page.

Comment: @Jon: Sure, but since they would be different extensions (there's no need to get rid of the `O(1)` space `MinBy` and `MaxBy`), the client would have to explicitly ask for it to take the `O(n)` space hit.

Comment: Yes, but my point is that we don't *need* to take an O(n) hit at all. At any point we can just work out the best item, if we can just express that elegantly.

Comment: @Jon: Ah, I get your point now. How about with `params Func<TSource, IComparable>[]`? Then we could do : `items.MaxBy(item => -item.Count, item => item.Value)`. Perhaps it isn't immediately obvious what the function does though.

Comment: I was wondering about that - the tricky part is then expressing that some are ascending and some descending...

Comment: @Jon: True, that would be tricky. In this particular case, it's relatively easy to dodge this by projecting to `-item.Count` (if we ignore the possibility of `int.MaxValue`). Personally, I don't mind the `O(n)` space issue over creating this magic operator that did everything for us efficiently. :) It would take an extremely perverse sequence for it to become a major issue.